# How does one Choose Life when Death has been decreed?

Tags: tanach, death, parashat-nitzavim, parashat-vezot-habracha

I’ve been thinking about Moshe up on Mt. Nebo and a question came to mind. If Death has been decreed, how does one continue to choose Life? Surely if one wishes to be obedient to G-d then one must in sense choose Death (or choose to die). Is there a nuance in the Hebrew words for Life and Death in [Devarim 30:19](//sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.30.19) where we're told to choose life, or in the language used to describe the death of the righteous ones in Tanakh, that I am not getting?

Comment: I think this is a metaphor. that fulling the commands is like having eternal "life" while rejecting them is as if you chose to be separated from G-d, life has no meaning, everything is dead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the site Tom, thank you for sharing your insightful question!

"Life" and "Death" are more than just physical terms - they are spiritual realities. Essentially, the Almighty urges us to "choose life" which the commentators explain refers to following His Torah and mitzvos to attain eternal life. (See [Seforno Devarim 30:19](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.30.19?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Sforno_on_Deuteronomy.30.19.1&lang2=bi) among many others) If Moshe were to choose 'physical life' against the Will of G-d, then that would not be following along the path of choosing *eternal* life. (Obviously, the case of an individual knowing when the Almighty wants someone to continue living a physical existence is beyond the realm of essentially everyone but a prophet, as we are also exhorted to live in this world as well - barring transgressing certain negative commandments like idolatry or murder)

Answer (score 1):

The only example you give of someone choosing death was someone who did so when instructed to by God. That's allowed: see "[Did HaShem ever command a Navi (Prophet) to break a law?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/108418/170)".